# What are the 29 tenets of the Bishnois?

Tags: philosophy, vaishnavism, sects, ahimsa

The Bisnois are said to be the foremost practitioners of Ahimsa and the greatest environmental activists. The 29 tenets of Bhisnois were formulated by Guru Jambheshwar. The following documentary mentions 29 tenets, but doesn't name every one of them. A list of these tenets along with a reference to a book documenting their belief system would be of great help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OX8bnlXyXro&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bishnoism is a Panjabi Vaishnava sect founded by Guru Jambheshwar in the 15th century.  [Here](http://www.bishnoism.com/bishnoi_29_principle/29_principle_detaill.php) are Jambheshwar's 29 principles:

> 1. “TEES DIN SUTAK” Observe 30 days of SUTAK (state of ritual impurity) after birth and keep mother & child away from household
>      activities.
> 2. “PANCH RITUVANTI NIYARO” During menstrual period, keep woman away from household activities for 5 days.
> 3. “SAIRO KARO SINAN” Take bath daily in the morning.
> 4. “SHEEL, SANTOSH, SUCHI PIYARO” Maintain good character, be content & maintain purity & cleanliness.
> 5. “DWI-KAL SANDHYA KARO” Pray two times a day (morning & evening).
> 6. “SANJH AARTI GUN GAO” Sing hymn of praise to the God in the evening.
> 7. “HOM HIT, CHIT, PREET SU HOY” Offer oblation in the holy fire (HAVAN) with feelings of welfare, devotion & love.
> 8. “PANI, INDHAN, DUDH NE LIJE CHHAN” Use filtered water, milk and cleaned firewood to make them bacteria/insects free.
> 9. “BANI NE LIJE CHHAN” Speak carefully (think before speak).
> 10. “EKSHMA HIRDE DHARO” Practise forgiveness/pardon/absolution from heart.
> 11. “DAYA HIRDE DHARO” Be compassionate/kind/merciful/sympathetic by heart.
> 12. “CHORI BARJIYO” Stealing or using other’s thing without permission is prohibited.
> 13. “NINDA BARJIYO” Condemnation/criticism is prohibited.
> 14. “JHUTH BARJIYO” Tell lies/untruthfulness is prohibited.
> 15. “BAD NA KARNO KOY” Don’t indulge in unnecessary dispute/debate/argument/controversy.
> 16. “AMAWAS VART RAKHNO” Observe fast on AMAWAS (last day of the dark half of a month).
> 17. “BHAJAN VISHNU BATAYO JOY” Worship & recite name of VISHNU in adoration.
> 18. “JEEV DAYA PALANI” Be compassionate/kind/merciful to all living beings.
> 19. “RUNKH LILA NAHI GHAVE” Don’t cut green trees.
> 20. “AJAR JARE JEEVAT MARE” Control/burn/win over AJARs(lust, anger, ego/pride, greed, attachment/infatuation/delusion).
> 21. “KARE RASOI HATH SU” Eat own/home cooked food. Don’t eat food cooked/kept in impure conditions.
> 22. “AMAR RAKHAVE THAT” Provide shelters for abandoned animals so that they can complete their life with dignity and don’ get slaughtered.
> 23. “BAIL BADHIYA NA KARAVE” Not to castrate bulls.
> 24. “AMAL SU DUR HI BHAGE” Don’t consume or trade in opium.
> 25. “TAMAKHU SU DUR HI BHAGE” Don’t smoke/use tobacco & its products.
> 26. “BHANG SU DUR HI BHAGE” Don’t consume or deal in narcotics.
> 27. “MADH SU DUR HI BHAGE” Don’t drink or deal in alcohol/liquor.
> 28. “MANS SU DUR HI BHAGE” Don’t eat meat or other non-vegetarian food.
> 29. “LEEL NA LAVE ANG” Don’t use violet blue colour extracted from green indigo plant.

See [here](http://www.bishnoism.com/bishnoi_29_principle/tees.php) for more detail on the 29 principles.  And see [here](http://www.bishnoism.com/bishnoi_literature/books.php) for a list of books on Bishnoism, although I don't see any English books there.

Answer (score 1):

Jambhoji showed the path of self-upliftment to men and women of every caste, class and varna and raised the lowly and fallen. Bishnoi Sampradaya is the path of Nivruti-means with the trend, which is also confirmed by its 29 religion rules.

Click on the link below to find out more about the Bishnoism, which has been involved in the preservation and enhancement of nature for centuries.
http://www.bishnoism.org
https://29rules.bishnoism.org
https://jambhvani.bishnoism.org

The 29 tenets of Bishnoism 
Observe a 30 day state of ritual impurity after child's birth and keep mother and child away from household activities.
Observe a 5 day segregation while a woman is in her menses.
Bathe daily in the morning before sunrise.
Obey the ideal rules of life: modesty, patience or satisfactions, cleanliness.
Pray twice everyday (morning and evening).
Eulogise God, Vishnu, in the evening (Aarti)
Perform Yajna (Havan) with the feelings of welfare devotion and love.
Use filtered water, milk and cleaned firewood.
Speak pure words in all sincerity.
Practice forgiveness from the heart.
Be merciful with sincerity.
Do not steal nor harbour any intention to do it.
Do not condemn or criticize.
Do not lie.
Do not indulge in dispute/debate.
Fast on Amavasya.
Worship and recite Lord Vishnu in adoration.
Be merciful to all living beings and love them.
Do not cut green trees, save the environment.
Crush lust, anger, greed and attachment.
Cook your food by yourself.
Provide shelters for abandoned animals to avoid them from being slaughtered in abattoirs.
Do not sterilise bulls.
Do not use or trade opium.
Do not smoke or use tobacco or its products.
Do not take bhang or hemp.
Do not drink alcohol/liquor.
Do not eat meat, always remain purely vegetarian.
Do not use violet blue colour extracted from the indigo plant.